# Ajax: Sending multiple parameters in HTTP POSTrequest

Tags: java, ajax, http, servlets, post

How to send multiple parametrs in HTTP POST request?
I am sending POST request through Ajax call to servlet
I tried below two ways but neither worked

Approach 1:

```
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost/Servlet/ps" , true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
.
.
.
httpRequest.send("msg="+data & "TC="+TC);
```

At Servlet:

```
String data = req.getParameter("msg"); // this prints value fine

String TestCaseNo = req.getParameter("TC"); // this prints null
```

Approach 2:

```
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost/Servlet/ps" , true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
.
.
.
httpRequest.send("msg="+data + "TC="+TC);
```

***ANSWER***:This is how it worked for me

```
var value="msg="+data+"&TC="+TC;
http-Request.send(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with AJAX but this seems more like a setup for GET request httpRequest.send("msg="+data & "TC="+TC).
Try writing parameters to your connection output stream and then in doPost method get it from req.getInputStream(). This will definitely work, but idk if it's exactly what your asking for.

Comment: I am not using I/O streams here, not sure what you are suggesting, any ex or link u can share

Comment: Tx but the answer i have provided in question, its easy then I/O streams and all !!